# Loading javascript plugs in order with gulp / browserify

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation, gulp, browserify

Soooooo.... I'm have a helluva time trying to figure out browserify.

Here's my app.js file:

```
var $ = require('../lib/jquery');
var foundation = require('../lib/foundation/foundation');

$(document).ready(function($){
    $(document).foundation();
});
```

when i try loading the browserified file, I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

I'm using the latest version of jquery. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Did you double check that `../lib/jquery` is pointing to the correct location?

Comment: yep, it's in the right location.

Answer (score 0):

so uh, i solved the problem by using browserify-shim

here's what i added to my package.json file:

```
"browser": {
  "jquery": "./js/lib/jquery.js"
},
"browserify-shim": {
  "jquery": "$"
},
"browserify": {
  "transform": [ "browserify-shim" ]
},
"dependencies": {
  "browserify-shim": "~3.2.0"
}
```

ta da

Comment: Unless you're also using three.js then I don't think "three" is needed in your `browserify-shim` property. Also, check out [exposify](https://github.com/thlorenz/exposify). This is from the same guy who wrote `browserify-shim`.